# How to create file-sync script between two folders using power-shell

Tags: powershell

The following script works best but the error comes when one of the folder is empty.

```
    $source="The source folder" 
    $target="The target folder" 

    $sourceFiles=Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse
    $targetFiles=Get-ChildItem -Path $target -Recurse

    $syncMode=2 

try{
$diff=Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourceFiles -DifferenceObject $targetFiles

foreach($f in $diff) {
    if($f.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
        $fullSourceObject=$f.InputObject.FullName
        $fullTargetObject=$f.InputObject.FullName.Replace($source, $target)

        Write-Host "Attemp to copy the following: " $fullSourceObject
        Copy-Item -Path $fullSourceObject -Destination $fullTargetObject
    }


    if($f.SideIndicator -eq "=>" -and $syncMode -eq 2) {
        $fullSourceObject=$f.InputObject.FullName
        $fullTargetObject=$f.InputObject.FullName.Replace($target,$source)

        Write-Host "Attemp to copy the following: " $fullSourceObject
        Copy-Item -Path $fullSourceObject -Destination $fullTargetObject
    }

}
}      
  catch {
  Write-Error -Message "something bad happened!" -ErrorAction Stop
 }
```

Is it possible to have empty folder while sync the two folders together ?

Comment: Can you rephrase what you want to do? What is the expected output? Please update the question to reflect that

Comment: As a generic advice, use RoboCopy instead...
or make sure the folders isn't empty.